# Cannot remove Apache noindex page

Tags: apache, centos

- CentOS 7.3.1611
- Apache httpd-2.4.6-45.el7.centos.x86_64

I need to replace the default Apache noindex page ("Testing 123..") with a config page for a dev environment.

I tried deleting it but it seems to have permanently cached itself somewhere on the server and I can't get rid of it. I've deleted `/etc/httpd/conf.d/welcome.conf` as well as the entire `/usr/share/httpd/noindex/` directory.

I've rebooted the server and verified it's not the client (same result on different client computers and browsers).

Is there some caching mechanism responsible for this? How do I clear it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attempting to change Apache's noindex processing is not a good idea. A better way to do it might be redirecting requests for "/" with a `LocationMatch` directive in `httpd.conf`

```
<LocationMatch "^/$">
   Redirect "/" "/config.php"
</LocationMatch>
```